# Is there a way to force Steam Cloud to sync?

Tags: steam, portal-2, steam-cloud

Right now, I have dual boot with Windows 7 and elementary OS(Linux), but my internet connection isn't working on Windows. I used to play Portal 2 a lot on Windows, and now I want to play it on Linux too, as it does have a version for Linux. But, when I ran the game, it didn't load my saved game, but it should, since Portal 2 supports Steam cloud.

Do I have to open Portal on Windows so it can sync? Shouldn't it be stored on the cloud? How do I force it to sync? After I closed Portal on Linux, it was written "Syncing" near Portal 2 on my games library, but nothing changed.

Comment: It could be that save games are not compatible between different operating systems. Depending on how the game saves, there might be a binary incompatibility. Games are generally synced from cloud to PC whens started and from PC to cloud when closed. Post your cloud log for Portal 2 please, you find it in Steam/Logs.

Comment: I was reading that question, but I don't have enough reputation to comment there. Let me see if I got this right:(english isn't my primary language) to make Steam sync I have to open the game on both machines at the same time?is that even possible?

Comment: Also look at: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50734/can-i-transfer-a-portal-2-saved-game-across-accounts-and-platforms

Comment: This should not have been closed. It is an individual problem since this is not simply about syncing like the other question, but about syncing between 2 different Operating Systems. And not every technical issue has the same solution.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness. My bad, I was too hasty with the duplicate. I vote to reopen.